# How to use enum on Sequel Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sequel

I am trying to use enum on my rails application that uses Sequel instead of Active Record.

How do i use enum when using Sequel instead of AR?

Comment: have you tired sequel_enum gem? https://github.com/planas/sequel_enum

Comment: You're welcome. Should I add it as an answer, so that we can close this thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functionality you're looking for is provided by Sequel's enum gem.

Checkout the [README](https://github.com/planas/sequel_enum) for implementation details.